# Jest unit testing error: Unexpected value imported by the module. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, jestjs

Im currently importing from my angular library in to my project the VisualWorkflowEditorModule modules, that imports ReteModule. The WorkflowEditorModule imports VisualWorkflowEditorModule. But i run the test from WorkflowEditorModule i get this error.

```
Unexpected value 'ReteModule' imported by the module 'VisualWorkflowEditorModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.
```

at the moment of running the app everthing is working just fine. just the test is not working.

**VisualWorkflowEditorModule**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReteModule } from 'rete-angular-plugin/16';
import { VisualWorkflowEditorComponent } from './visual-workflow-editor.component';
import { CustomSocketComponent } from './customization/custom-socket/custom-socket.component';
import { CustomNodeComponent } from './customization/custom-node/custom-node.component';
import { CustomConnectionComponent } from './customization/custom-connection/custom-connection.component';
import { EditorCreatorService } from './edtitor-creator';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [VisualWorkflowEditorComponent, CustomSocketComponent, CustomNodeComponent, CustomConnectionComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, ReteModule],
  providers: [EditorCreatorService],
  exports: [VisualWorkflowEditorComponent],
})
export class VisualWorkflowEditorModule {}
```

**WorkflowEditorModule**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonEditorComponent } from '@exb/json-editor';
import { TranslocoModule } from '@ngneat/transloco';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { ConfirmDialogModule } from 'primeng/confirmdialog';
import { SplitterModule } from 'primeng/splitter';

import { AppHeaderComponent, MermaidViewComponent, ReadOnlyDirective } from '@exb/components';

import { WorkflowEditorRoutingModule } from './workflow-editor-routing.module';
import { WorkflowEditorComponent } from './workflow-editor.component';
import { IsReadonlySolutionPipe } from '../../pipes/is-readonly-solution.pipe';
import { VisualWorkflowEditorModule } from '@exb/workflow-editor';
import { FeatureAllowedModule } from '../../../lib/directives/is-feature-allow/feature-allowed.module';
import { InputSwitchModule } from 'primeng/inputswitch';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [WorkflowEditorComponent],
  imports: [
    AppHeaderComponent,
    ButtonModule,
    CommonModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    JsonEditorComponent,
    MermaidViewComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SplitterModule,
    TranslocoModule,
    VisualWorkflowEditorModule,
    FeatureAllowedModule,
    WorkflowEditorRoutingModule,
    IsReadonlySolutionPipe,
    ReadOnlyDirective,
    InputSwitchModule,
  ],
})
export class WorkflowEditorModule {}
```

**WorkflowEditor test**

```
describe('WorkflowEditorComponent', () => {
  let component: RenderResult<WorkflowEditorComponent>;
  let workflowServiceMock: Partial<jest.MockedObject<WorkflowService>>;
  let workflow$: Subject<Workflow | undefined>;
  let nativeEditorWrapperMock: NativeEditorWrapperMock;
  let confirmDialogServiceMock: Partial<jest.MockedObject<ConfirmationDialogService>>;
  let solutionPermissionServiceMock: Partial<jest.MockedObject<SolutionPermissionService>>;
  let confirmResult$: Subject<ConfirmEventType>;
  let showErrorSpy: jest.SpyInstance;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {});

    workflow$ = new Subject<Workflow | undefined>();
    workflowServiceMock = {
      getWorkflow: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(workflow$.asObservable()),
      setWorkflow: jest.fn().mockImplementation(workflow => of(workflow)),
    };
    nativeEditorWrapperMock = new NativeEditorWrapperMock();
    confirmResult$ = new Subject<ConfirmEventType>();
    confirmDialogServiceMock = {
      confirmUnsavedChanges: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => confirmResult$.asObservable()),
    };
    solutionPermissionServiceMock = {
      hasReadOnlyPermissions: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false),
    };

    component = await render(WorkflowEditorComponent, {
      imports: [WorkflowEditorModule, ApolloTestingModule, TranslocoTestingRootModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: { snapshot: { paramMap: new Map<string, string>([['solutionId', solutionId]]) } },
        },
        { provide: NATIVE_EDITOR_WRAPPER_FACTORY, useValue: { createEditor: () => nativeEditorWrapperMock } },
        { provide: WorkflowService, useValue: workflowServiceMock },
        { provide: ConfirmationDialogService, useValue: confirmDialogServiceMock },
        { provide: SolutionPermissionService, useValue: solutionPermissionServiceMock },
      ],
    });

    showErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(TestBed.inject(ToastsMessageService), 'showError');
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
```